# Accesando elementos aninados en un JSON desde un template Django

Tags: python, django, json

Tengo el siguiente documento `JSON`

```
{
  "paciente": {
    "id": 1234,
    "nombre": "Pablo Andrés Agudelo Marenco",
    "sesion": {
      "id": 12345,
      "juego": [
        {
          "nombre": "bonzo",
          "nivel": [
            {
              "id": 1234,
              "nombre": "caida libre",
              "segmento": [
                {
                  "id": 12345,
                  "nombre": "Hombro",
                  "movimiento": [
                    {
                      "id": 1234,
                      "nombre": "Flexion",
                      "metricas": [
                        {
                          "min": 12,
                          "max": 34,
                          "media": 23,
                          "moda": 20
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "id": 12345,
                      "nombre": "Extensión",
                      "metricas": [
                        {
                          "min": 12,
                          "max": 34,
                          "media": 23,
                          "moda": 20
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "id": 12345,
                  "nombre": "Escápula",
                  "movimiento": [
                    {
                      "id": 1234,
                      "nombre": "Protracción",
                      "metricas": [
                        {
                          "min": 12,
                          "max": 34,
                          "media": 23,
                          "moda": 20
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "id": 12345,
                      "nombre": "Retracción",
                      "metricas": [
                        {
                          "min": 12,
                          "max": 34,
                          "media": 23,
                          "moda": 20
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "___léeme___": "El array 'iteraciones' contiene las vitorias o derrotas con el tiempo en segundos de cada iteración",
              "iteraciones": [
                {
                  "victoria": true,
                  "tiempo": 120
                },
                {
                  "victoria": false,
                  "tiempo": 232
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Este documento a pesar de tener una estructura definida, en el arreglo `segmento` dependiendo de si es el caso o no pueden venir unos datos y en ocasiones no.

Asi las cosas, algunas veces el elemento `segmento` puede tener uno, dos y hasta tres valores dentro de su array.

```
"paciente": ...
   "sesion": ...
       "juego": ...
           **"segmento":[{"id": ...,"nombre":...},{"id": ...,"nombre":...},{"id": ...,"nombre":...}]**
```

Yo debo mostrar los valores de `segmento.nombre` en un template de la siguiente manera:

Cada valor de `segmento.nombre` debe mostrarse en un `html div` tab, asi por ejemplo, si mi documento JSON llega con dos elementos en el array `segmento`

```
{
  "segmento": [{
    "id": 12345,
    "nombre": "Escapula",
  }, {
    "id": 12345,
    "nombre": "Hombro",
  }]
}
```

Entonces, se deben mostrar estos dos valores en el template de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El documento JSON lo leo de esta forma:**

```
<code> ...
with open('ProcessedMetrics.json') as data_file:
            session_data=json.loads(data_file.read())
            context['session_data'] = session_data
<code> ...
```

**Y en el template, estoy haciendo lo siguiente:**

```
 <!-- begin corporal segments tabs -->
  <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
    {% for nest1 in session_data.paciente.sesion.juego %}
        {% for nest2 in nest1.items %} <!-- get all games (juego array)-->
            {%for nest3 in nest2%}
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active">                                  
                        <a href="#mano" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true"><i class="fa fa-check-square">{{nest3}}</i> 
                                            </a></li>   

            {%endfor%}    
        {%endfor%}    
    {%endfor%}    
                    <li><a href="#codo" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> other tab hardcoded</a></li>
                </ul>
```

El resultado que obtengo hasta el momento es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede detallar, capturé los valores de juego y la clave nivel.

Tengo dificultades para avanzar al valor de la clave `nivel` y de ahi al array `segmento`

¿Cómo podría acceder a estos elementos de una forma óptima?
La idea que quiero es poder generar tantos tabs como documentos de segmento existan en su array `segmento`

---

- **ACTUALIZACIÓN**

De acuerdo a la respuesta dada por [@German-Alzate-Martinez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15252/german-alzate-martinez), además de ello, he querido adicionar la forma en como correlacionar los tabs que se generen  en relación al contenido de la clave `segmento`, la cual es un array en mi archivo JSON

Lo importante a tener en cuenta esta en el atributo href del tab (dentro del `ul` y el `div`)en donde se define un identificador (`#`) el cual en mi caso es el nombre del segmento (`href="#{{nest3.nombre}}"`)

Además de esto, en el contenido de ese tab, se realiza la correlación con ese tab creado  en la clase`tab-pane` con el `id="{{nest3.nombre}}"`

Esto es de esta forma:

```
<div class="box-body">
    <!-- begin corporal segments tabs -->
        <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                {% for nest1 in session_data.paciente.sesion.juego %}
                    {% for nest2 in nest1.nivel %} 
                        {%for nest3 in nest2.segmento%}
                            <li><a href="#{{nest3.nombre}}" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> {{nest3.nombre}}</a></li>
                        {%endfor%}
                    {%endfor%}
                {%endfor%}    
            </ul>
<!--- Content of tabs generated above -->                                   
<div class="tab-content">
    {% for nest1 in session_data.paciente.sesion.juego %}
        {% for nest2 in nest1.nivel %}
            {%for nest3 in nest2.segmento%}

            <!-- /.tab-pane  Correlation with href tab above-->

                <div class="tab-pane" id="{{nest3.nombre}}">
                <!-- The timeline -->
                    <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
                       .... More code ....
                    </div>
               </div>
        ......
 </div>
```

Es de esta forma en como yo puedo generar tabs específicos acorde al número de valores de segmentos que vengan en mi clave/array `segmento` en el archivo JSON que he leido, además asocio a esos tabs con su respectivo contenido.

Lo que no he mirado bien es:

Si miramos, en el documento JSON fuente de mis datos, los segmentos tienen determinados movimientos, los cuales están anidados dentro del tab `segmento` que es un array, al final del día:

Para ello enfatizo a continuación la porción de mi documento JSON en donde esto ocurre:

```
{

    "segmento": [{
        "id": 12345,
        "nombre": "Hombro",
        "movimiento": [{
            "id": 1234,
            "nombre": "Flexion",
            "metricas": [{
                "min": 12,
                "max": 34,
                "media": 23,
                "moda": 20
            }]
        }, {
            "id": 12345,
            "nombre": "Extensión",
            "metricas": [{
                "min": 12,
                "max": 34,
                "media": 23,
                "moda": 20
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 12345,
        "nombre": "Escápula",
        "movimiento": [{
            "id": 1234,
            "nombre": "Protracción",
            "metricas": [{
                "min": 12,
                "max": 34,
                "media": 23,
                "moda": 20
            }]
        }, {
            "id": 12345,
            "nombre": "Retracción",
            "metricas": [{
                "min": 12,
                "max": 34,
                "media": 23,
                "moda": 20
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Lo que deseo y no he podido lograr es que cuando yo hago un click en un tab o pestaña, es que si el segmento es `Hombro`, por ejemplo, solo me aparezcan los movimientos que estan anidados dentro del array `movimiento` que esta dentro de segmentos en el JSON.

Asi mismo también las métricas (array `metricas`) que estan dentro del array de `movimiento`.

De momento, y como puede verse acá, https://nrhb.herokuapp.com/sesiones-de-rehabilitacion/3 en cada tab que se genera dinámicamente acorde al número de segmentos que trae el array `segmento` se pintan  todos los movimientos que tiene el documento sin importar si pertenecen a un segmento en particular.

Es decir, si hago click en el tab de `Hombro`, me salen los movimientos anidados que tiene el segmento  `Hombro` y los de `Escápula` y asi en el tab de `Escápula` también.

Esto ocurre porque en el contenido de cada tab en mi template html en el `div` con clase  `tab-pane`  después de mostrar la tabla, en su `td` o registro respectivo estoy diciendo que accedo al array movimiento con un nuevo indice dado por un ciclo for

(buscar mas abajo la sección de ciclos anidados en donde dice `{% for nest4 in nest3.movimiento %}`) y ahi estoy pintando `<td>{{nest4.nombre}}</td>`

Lo mismo en el ciclo `{% for nest5 in nest4.metricas %}` en donde ubico cada valor con el indice `nest5`, para el caso del array `metricas`

```
<div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
               <h3>Métricas</h3>
                <tbody>
                     <tr>
                           <th></th>
                            <th>Movimientos</th>
                            <th>Minimo</th>
                            <th>Maximo</th>
                            <th>Media</th>
                            <th>Moda</th>
                            </tr>
                              {% for nest1 in session_data.paciente.sesion.juego %}
                                  {% for nest2 in nest1.nivel %}
                                      {% for nest3 in nest2.segmento %}
                                          {% for nest4 in nest3.movimiento %}
                                    <tr>
                                         <td>
                                                <i class="fa  fa-hand-rock-o pull-right"></i>
                                          </td>

                    <!-- Ubicando los nombres de los movimientos , pero salen todos los elementos de ese array -->                  

                                          <td>{{nest4.nombre}}
                                          </td>
                                                           {% for nest5 in nest4.metricas %}
                                           <!-- Ubicando los valores de las metricas , pero salen todos los elementos de ese array -->
                                                    <td>{{nest5.min}}</td>
                                                     <td>{{nest5.max}}</td>
                                                      <td>{{nest5.media}}</td>
                                                      <td>{{nest5.moda}}</td>

                                          {% endfor %}
                                      {% endfor %}
                                   {% endfor %}
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endfor %} 

                      </tr>
                  </tbody> 
           </table>
   </div>
```

Entonces mi inquietud que la hice bastante larga porque quise especificar detalles por si fuesen necesarios es como puedo filtrar en los `td` o registros que me salgan los movimientos respectivos de un segmento y las metricas respectivas de un movimiento y asi poder dar utilidad a cada tab o pestaña.

Espero no haber sido inoportuno con esta consulta, y su ayuda u orientación será altaamente apreciada.

Comment: Para mi gusto, hay demasiada lógica en la plantilla. Supongo que la generación del archivo json es un requisito, pero en todo caso, __además__ de enviar el json a tu plantilla, en la vista donde lo generas, genera también un diccionario con los mismos datos y ocupa ese diccionario para crear tu página...

Comment: @toledano ¿me dices que crear un diccionario sin nada de arrays o anidaciones y en base a esos valores extraerlos más fácilmente en el template?

Comment: Los diccionarios pueden contener lo que quieras: mas diccionarios, listas, tuplas, etc. Lo que te digo, es que para las plantillas es más fácil procesar un diccionario o un tipo nativo de Python que un JSON.  Además, la clave de un diccionario la puedes procesar con un custom tag y generar html en Django y no en la plantilla. El chiste es que tus plantillas son tontitas y no deben hacer cosas complicadas, porque son tontitas.

Comment: Lo que me comentas es una muy buena opción para evitar un procesamiento del lado de los templates, pero para recorrer ese diccionario sería igual dependiendo de las anidaciones, solo que en la vista según me cuentas ¿verdad? ¿Qué tipos de custom tags procesarían las claves y generarían htmls desde la vista para ser pasados al template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno lo que veo que mas te puede ayudar seria recorrer sin items, es decir...

```
...
<div class="nav-tabs-custom">
{% for nest1 in session_data.paciente.sesion.juego %}
    {% for nest2 in nest1.nivel %} <!-- get all games (juego array)-->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            {%for nest3 in nest2.segmento %}
                <li class="active">                                  
                    <a href="#mano" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true"><i class="fa fa-check-square">{{nest3.nombre}}</i> 
                    </a>
                </li>
            {%endfor%}
            <li>
                <a href="#codo" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> other tab hardcoded</a>
            </li>  
        </ul>
    {%endfor%}    
{%endfor%}
</div>
...
```

Si te das cuenta, ya no estoy recorriendo por items si no que voy al item que me interesa segun el JSON, que primero viene el array de niveles, y luego el de segmentos... sin embargo, veo que esto pueda ocacionarte errores a futuro, no se si tienes esto asi definido por alguna razón, pero lo mejor seria que sacaras el tag de `<ul>` de todos los ciclos, asi te aseguras que lo único que se repita sean los `<li>`, un ejemplo seria...

```
...
<div class="nav-tabs-custom">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        {% for nest1 in session_data.paciente.sesion.juego %}
            {% for nest2 in nest1.nivel %} <!-- get all games (juego array)-->
                {%for nest3 in nest2.segmento %}
                <li class="active">                                  
                    <a href="#mano" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true"><i class="fa fa-check-square">{{nest3.nombre}}</i> 
                    </a>
                </li>
                {%endfor%}
                <li>
                    <a href="#codo" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> other tab hardcoded</a>
                </li>
            {%endfor%}    
        {%endfor%}
    </ul>
</div>
...
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Me ha funcionado para generar un tab por cada segmento que se lee del documento JSON. Tengo una inquietud y es que cada div en donde se genera el tab tiene un respectivo content que es en otro div, de acuerdo a esto, los meti dentro del primer ciclo, pero me los muestra de manera seguida .. algo asi como esto  https://cldup.com/XguiDM6yMb.png

Comment: @bgarcial no entiendo mucho tu inquietud, no se si quieras abrir otra pregunta con tu inquietud

Comment: entiendo, voy a tratar de efectuar una actualización o realizar otra pregunta. :)

Comment: he efectuado una actualización a mi inquietud, en relación a un avance que pude realizar tomando en cuenta tu respuesta y algo mas que hice. La actualización salió un poco larga pero es porque quise detallar mi inquietud, pero ésta va en la misma línea de lo que me ayudaste en tu respuesta por lo que no es tediosa la lectura. Te agradezco tu oreintación en caso de ser posible y muchas gracias :)